# Missing layer when following tutorial

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've followed [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/66877/how-to-make-a-game-like-candy-crush-part-1) tutorial to get a hang of spritekit, however ran into a problem with the 'tilelayer' which is supposed to draw grey sprites behind each valid tile. I used didMoveToView() instead of initWithSize() since it's supposedly correct practice nowadays, however the tilelayer didn't show up (the background and cookielayer DO show up). When I moved the following code into initWithSize() instead (and changed around the viewcontroller appropriately to call that instead), the tilelayer showed up.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

self.swipeFromColumn = self.swipeFromRow = NSNotFound;

self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
[self addChild:background];


//gamelayer
self.gameLayer = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:self.gameLayer];

CGPoint layerPosition = CGPointMake(-TileWidth*NumColumns/2, -TileHeight*NumRows/2);


self.tilesLayer = [SKNode node];
self.tilesLayer.position = layerPosition;


//add tiles layer
[self.gameLayer addChild:self.tilesLayer];

self.cookiesLayer = [SKNode node];
self.cookiesLayer.position = layerPosition;


//add cookies layers
[self.gameLayer addChild:self.cookiesLayer];

self.swipeFromColumn = self.swipeFromRow = NSNotFound;

self.selectionSprite = [SKSpriteNode node];

[self preloadResources];
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs about `didMoveToView`:

> Called immediately after a scene is presented by a view.

**didMoveToView vs initWithSize**

`didMoveToView` is used often instead of `initWithSize` because of two main reasons:

1) Nowadays, the scene is being loaded from .sks file by default, so `initWithSize` isn't called actually. Instead, `initWithCoder` is called.

2) If you are positioning your scene elements based on a view size, you can't do that inside of a `initWithSize` because at that time, the view is `nil`. So you have to wait for the scene being presented first. After that, self.view (where `self` is a scene) is not nil anymore, and `didMoveToView` is called.

**The Order of Program Execution**

Right now, things seems to go like this in your code (I am talking about the original version of the code):

- `viewDidLoad`
- `initWithSize` is called
- level is initialized
- addTiles method is called //this is what creates your *gray* tiles
- scene is presented
- `didMoveToView` is called //you don't actually use it, but this is the moment when it is called

**The Cause of the Problem**

So you get a picture? At the moment of calling `addTiles` method on a scene, you don't have required stuff initialized (the stuff from `initWithSize`), because you moved all that (postponed its execution) inside of a `didMoveToView`. I don't have time to look closely into tutorial, but something in that method fails, probably this:

`if ([self.level tileAtColumn:column row:row] != nil) {...}`

Add an else block and see if it is executed (I can bet it will), or print what is being used inside of that block and you will find the issue,   because that is the part of the code which adds those grey layers to `self.tilesLayer`

Bottom line, if you want to follow todays practices, then follow new tutorials (that is tutorial from 2014). I mean, there are a lot of nice stuff there, but you can't just expect that what you see these days on the internet can easily fit into something that is written two years ago ...  Try to understand what is going on in the tutorial instead of just copy pasting the code. Also, as I said, using `didMoveToView` is not a practice. There is a reason ( see above ) why you might want to use it instead of scene's init.

Comment: Aha, you got it. The if-statement is still true, but self.tilesLayer is null which means nothing happens anyway. Thanks for the long explanation. If you have any suggestions for more recent tutorials I'd certainly want to hear!

Comment: @Cesar You can find some great things here (Apple's DemoBots game) : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Your tiles layer is a generic SKNode, if you want it to be gray, you need to add the background color.  The tutorial you provided doesn't use gray from what I see, maybe you are reading it wrong

edit:

Did you do this part of the tutorial?

> Add the following method to RWTMyScene.m, as well:
>
> ```
> - (void)addTiles {
>   for (NSInteger row = 0; row < NumRows; row++) {
>     for (NSInteger column = 0; column < NumColumns; column++) {
>       if ([self.level tileAtColumn:column row:row] != nil) {
>         SKSpriteNode *tileNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Tile"];
>         tileNode.position = [self pointForColumn:column row:row];
>         [self.tilesLayer addChild:tileNode];
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You’ll need to call this method from other classes, so open
>   RWTMyScene.h and add the method declaration there:
>
> ```
> - (void)addTiles;
> ```
>
> Next, open RWTViewController.m. Add the following line to viewDidLoad,
>   immediately after you set self.scene.level:
>
> ```
> [self.scene addTiles];
> ```

Comment: I haven't noticed your edit, lol (I was into writing my own answer).  And same as you,  I am pretty positive that `addTiles` method is the source of the problem. Still, I will left my answer because it describes some more details about this issue.

Comment: I have all those parts of the tutorial. As i said, the tiles layer works correctly when i move the pasted code from didMoveToView to initWithSize, i just don't understand why.

Comment: @Cesar, Where are you doing it though,  if you are calling `addTiles` in the `ViewDidLoad`, and you are calling everything else in didMoveToView, then you have a timing issue, because `ViewDidLoad` happens before `didMoveToView`